# Exporting data with NTEXT columns to Excel in a regularly basis (as Job)

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, export

**Initial situation:**
I'm stuck in a simple task (in my opinion it should be simple...)
I have a collection of data which should be exported weekly to Excel.
This export contains 104 columns, from which 57 are nvarchar(max) and contains item descriptions and other information in different languages for our sales guys.
The report will have something around 2000 to 8000 rows.
I use a SQL Server 2017 CU 16

**My intention:**
I intended to do an SSI Job with an Excel template where the columns are predefined (width, data type and so on).

This job would have something like those steps:

1. Delete existing Excel file
2. copy Excel template as a new Excel file
3. DataFlowTask using SQL Server as the source and Excel destination as the target

**What I already tried:**
If I use the excel template with only headers, I get the following error for each of the nvarchar(max) columns:

> [Excel Destination [2]] Error: An error occurred while setting up a
>   binding for the "ColumnName" column. The binding status was
>   "DT_NTEXT".

When I prepare the template having it prefilled with one row. This row has a long text (more than 255 characters) for the columns where nvarchar(max) is in the source, everything runs fine but, this dummy line is still existing.

Another try I did was dropping the sheet using an "Execute SQL Task" to the Excel File Connection and recreating the sheet using a create table statement in another "Execute SQL Task" to the same Excel file connection, I get the same error as above. Although I'm using NTEXT as the datatype for the relevant columns.

**Question:**
How can I export data seamlessly into a preformatted excel file which contains NTEXT?

Thank you very much in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Create a view in the source db wich converts NTEXT to NVARCHAR. Use NVARCHAR in all the SSIS package setup.

Comment: the data I export is already set as nvarchar(max). NTEXT is the corresponding datatype, Excel should have on the target side.

Comment: "The problem is that when the JET engine pulls in the Excel spreadsheet it will (by default) read just the first 8 rows to determine what the column datatype should be"  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ssis-excel-and-dt_ntext Looks like you need the dummy row.

Comment: This' ridiculous, isn't it?
How to delete this dummy line programmatically?

Comment: Use a Script Task to delete the dummy line after the data has been loaded to the Excel file.